# How to find average successful search when elements are NOT equally likely to be searched (linear and BST)

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, linear-search

I'm learning searching and I want to know the average successful search for both linear and BST when each element is NOT equally likely to be searched. However, I haven't had much luck finding what to do in such cases :(

For example, I have a list of 3 elements (5, 4, 8) with probability of each element being searched is (0.1, 0.05, 0.05) respectively. What is the average number of elements inspected for a successful search if linear search or BST is performed?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but in a case where the probability of certain searches was known to be greater than others I probably wouldn't use a general purpose search anyway but opt instead for a scheme that takes advantage of the prior knowledge e.g. by keeping often-searched keys closer to the root.

Comment: Can you edit in the rest of that example? You've included the input, but it's not clear what the output should be and why that should be the output.

Comment: For a `successful search`? Then `search-probability` can be tossed, as you're only searching for one of the `(5, 4, 8)`. Then for linear `(1, 2, 3)` & binary `(2, 1, 2)` respectively. But for any search, linear `(2*0.2 + 3 * 0.8) = 2.8`; binary `(1.67*0.2 + 2*0.8) = 1.934` average searches for 3 elements with those probabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup is that element `i` has a value `v[i]`, a probability `p[i]` and a search for that element will do `c[i]` comparisons.

In your example we are given

```
v = [5, 4, 8]
p = [0.1, 0.05, 0.05]
```

If you attempt a linear search, the number of comparisons will be

```
c = [1, 2, 3]
```

What you do is weight each count by the likelihood of doing it, divided by the overall likelihood of a successful search.  That is:

```
print(sum([p[i] * c[i] for i in range(len(c))]) / sum(p))
```

In your case this comes out to `1.75`.

If you were to switch to a binary search, the counts change to `c = [1, 2, 2]` and the calculation instead comes out to `1.5`.  (Which makes sense, you have even odds of picking the root or a leaf.)

If you want to include the possibility of unsuccessful searches, then you just add counts and probabilities for the unsuccessful searches.  So for linear you might get:

```
p = [0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.8]
c = [1, 2, 3, 3]
```

and now your answer is `2.75`.  That's because you're mostly doing unsuccessful searches, which take `3`.

For an unbalanced binary search it gets more complicated because you have to include each missing range with a probability.  But the principle remains the same.